# Replace HTML tag with a new tag

Tags: jquery

How can I replace the `html` tag with a new tag using jQuery?

I have many `table` tags and I want to replace a specific table containing a class. All of its' child nodes should be replaced too.

```
<table class='replace_this'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            All table, tr, and td tag are replaced with div tag
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Should be changed to:

```
<div class='replace_this'>
    <div>
        <div>
            All table, tr, and td tag are replaced with div tag
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to start from the inside out:

```
$('.replace_this td').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<div>' + this.innerHTML + '</div>')
    })
});

$('.replace_this tr').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<div>' + this.innerHTML + '</div>')
    })
});

$('table.replace_this ').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(function() {
        return $('<div class="replace_this">' + this.innerHTML + '</div>')
    })
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KqZeZ/3)

Comment: Damn you Mike, was 3/4 of the way through writing the fiddle with the exact same :)

Comment: Good, but he did ask for a specific class only ;)

Comment: `class` attribute is missing in the top `div` element.

Comment: one question, how can i select the text inside the div and wrap it in "<p>" tag?

Comment: `return $('<div><p>' + this.innerHTML + '</p></div>')` just add a p tag

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:

```
$.each(['td', 'tr', 'table'], function(index, value){
    $(value).replaceWith(function() {
      return '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
    });
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/nHpCc/4/

Comment: `class` attribute is missing in the top `div` element.